Alternative to --from-local-d1 `prisma migrate diff`
I have followed the tutorial here - https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/cloudflare-d1#3-generate-sql-statements-using-prisma-migrate-diff
I ran this command:
npx prisma migrate diff \
  --from-empty \
  --to-schema-datamodel ./prisma/schema.prisma \
  --script \
  --output migrations/0001_create_user_table.sql

It works great. However I don't want to apply this migration yet. I want to make some more changes to the schema (add a "color" column to the "User" model), and then I want to run npx prisma migrate diff to a 2nd file called migrations/0002_add_user_color.sql.
However the docs only show show how to do this with --from-local-d1. Is there a way to make npx prisma migrate diff just look at the existing migrations and go from there?
